# $\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)\cos nx =0$ for all non negative integer n then prove $f(x)$ is identically $0$ on $[0, \pi]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, continuity, riemann-integration

If $f$ belongs to $C[0, \pi]$ and $f(0) = 0$. Determine the cases where the given condition implies that $f$ is identically zero.

Case 1     $\int_{0}^{\pi}\ x^nf(x) =0$     for all non negative integer n

Case 2    $\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)\cos nx =0$    for all non negative integer n

Case 3  $\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)\sin nx =0$    for all positive integer n

What I know is if $f(x)$ greater or equal to $0$ in the interval then $\int_{0}^{\pi}\ f(x) =0$ implies $f(x) = 0$.If I use  Weierstrass approximation theorem I would get the first case done. But I can not understand how to proceed for last two cases. Can anyone help me out?  For your information all the cases are true.

Answer (score 4):

Case 2: Extend $f$ to $F$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$ so that $F$ is even. Then the evenness of $F(x)$ and $\cos nx$ shows

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}F(x)\cos nx\,dx = 2\int_0^{\pi}f(x)\cos nx\,dx = 0$$

for $n=0,1,2,\dots.$ Now use the evenness of $F(x)$ and the oddness of $\sin nx$ to see $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}F(x)\sin nx\,dx = 0,$$ $n=1,2,\dots.$ Thus all of $F$'s Fourier coefficients are $0.$ By Parseval's theorem,

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|F(x)|^2\, dx = 0.$$

The continuity of $F$ then implies $F\equiv 0.$ Because $F=f$ on $[0,\pi],$ we have $f\equiv 0.$

Case 3: See if you can solve this case using ideas similar to the above.

Comment: Why did u need Parseval's theorem? $a_n = 0$ for every $n\geq 0$ and $b_n =0 $ for every $n\geq 1$...So by fourier series expansion $F(x) = 0$ for all $x\in[-\pi , \pi]$@zhw.

Comment: And where $f(0) = 0$ will be used?

Comment: @cmi is right : to conclude that 'all of F's Fourier coefficient are 0', you have to mention that $F(0)=0$, so its coefficient $a_0=0$ (otherwise you can only conclude that F is constant)

Comment: I did not get u...Can u please elaborate?

Comment: @cmi The Fourier expansion of a continuous function $g$ does not need to converge to $g$ everywhere. However, Parseval always holds. That's how I get $F\equiv 0.$

Comment: @cmi $f(0)=0$ is used in claiming $F$ is continuous.

Comment: @charMD It is given that that the cosine integral is $0$ for $n=0,$ so we're fine.

Comment: Can U tell me why u are needing Parseval's theorem? Every $a_n$ and  $b_n$ is $0$ ,  How the fourier Expansion can be divergent for some $x$?@zhw.

Comment: Can U tell me why u are needing Parseval's theorem? Every an
and bn is 0 , How the fourier Expansion can be divergent for some x?@zhw.

Comment: @sani How would you prove this: If $f$ is continuous on $[-\pi,\pi]$ and all of $f $'s Fourier coefficents are $0,$ then $f\equiv 0?$

Comment: Can You please tell me how $f$ can be extended to an even function $F$?@zhw.

Comment: For $x\in [-\pi,0],$ define $F(x)= f(-x).$  @cmi

Comment: Yes..Can you please explain me what will happen when https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2597115/f-in-c-pi-pi-and-if-int-pi-pi-fx-sin-nx-mathrm-dx-0-th

Comment: What will happen in case 3? extending to a even function will not help..@zhw