# $f\in c([-\pi,\pi])$ and if $\int_{-\pi}^\pi ~f(x) \sin (nx) \mathrm dx$ =$0$ then prove that $f(x) = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-series

$f\in c([-\pi,\pi])$ and if $\int_{-\pi}^\pi ~f(x) \sin(nx) \mathrm dx$ =$0$  then prove that $f(x) = 0$.  Can anyone please help me to solve it?

I was trying to understand this [$\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)\cos nx =0$ for all non negative integer n then prove $f(x)$ is identically $0$ on $[0, \pi]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2299702/int-0-pifx-cos-nx-0-for-all-non-negative-integer-n-then-prove-fx?noredirect=1&lq=1) where $cosnx$ is there in the place of $sinnx$. But I got some questions.

1) How $f$ can  extended to a even function?

2) what will happen when $sinnx$ is there in the place of $cosnx$?

Comment: question and headline don't match (sin / cos)

Comment: $n$ is integer, correct?

Comment: What if $f$ is odd/even (headline/question)?

Comment: i have already answered ths question, use the fourier decomposition

Comment: I read the answer.. I have mentioned where did I get stuck....@TsemoAristide

Comment: This is obviously false, take $f\equiv 1$

Comment: Why did you copy the proof I gave at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2299702/int-0-pifx-cos-nx-0-for-all-non-negative-integer-n-then-prove-fx/2300363?noredirect=1#comment5362444_2300363 word for word, and not give a link instead?

Comment: Edited.............................